# c# replace string with many "x"

Tags: c#

I am writing a windows form app in C#. I have a label with a random word, e.g. "computer". User has to guess what is this word by guessing letter by letter. But word "computer" must be replaced with as many "x" as there is letters in a word, so in this example user should see "xxxxxxxx".

I tried to replace it with regex like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    word.Text = Regex.Replace(word.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$", "x");
}
```

But it only replace with single "x".

I also tried with for loop, but the result is the same:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= word.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        word.Text = Regex.Replace(word.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$", "x");
    }
}
```

Comment: you need replace computer word to xxxx from text? It is "my text computer".Replace("computer", "x-x-x")

Comment: look at your code: you are replacing _any amount of letters_ with _one_ x. what you should do is replace _one_ of any letter with _one_ x. try removing the `+` (which says: one or more of the previous item)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann while I remove + it doesn't replace any letter

Comment: You can simply use PadRight(). ie: var xxx = "".PadRight(word.Text.Length, 'x'); Or, it looks like you are using winforms, you could use a password textbox.

Comment: why not use built in `passwordchar` of textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new string of "x" repeated the number of characters in your word. No need for regexes.

```
word.Text = new string('x', word.Text.Length);
```

Comment: A minor correction to this answer, `new string()` expects a `char` therefore, it would be single quote around as in `"x" => 'x'`

Answer (score 1):

Approach without `RegEx`

```
string wordText = "computer";
wordText = string.Concat(wordText.Select(x => char.IsLetter(x) ? 'x' : x));
```

---

if you want to stay with `RegEx`, replace `@"^[a-zA-Z]+$"` with `"[a-zA-Z]"` to match every single character

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
word.Text=String.Join("",word.Text.Select(s=>s='x').ToArray());
```